# Google REST API : Unable to fetch mails for a particular label

Tags: javascript, google-api

For fetching labels i used get request 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/UserId/labels'.

However, I am unable to fetch mails for specific labels.  I want to fetch particular labels mails (such as Inbox, Sent-mails) using the Google mail REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the labels should be provided in upper case, e.g.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/labels/INBOX
```

If you provide the label ID in another format - e.g. `inbox` or `Inbox`, the call fails with a 404 not found code and message.

You can get a list of available labels for a user using api endpoint without any label ID.  This will show you all the available labels that you can retrieve:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/labels
```

The only valid ID's are those in the ID field of each JSON object in the returned labels List.

***EDIT***

OP clarified in comments that they wish to actually retrieve the messages, rather than Label information.

To do that - you need to use a different API endpoint

```
https://content.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages
```

This takes the optional LabelIds parameter e.g.

```
https://content.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages?labelIds=INBOX
```

This will return a list of message IDs and thread IDs which in turn can be used to retrieve individual messages or threads if required (using the messages endpoint [get functionality](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)).

Note that the google [documentation for the API is here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/), with specifics for the [messages endpoint list functionality here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list), including a feature where you can try it out with label IDs.  Note the valid label IDs are still the ones returned above.

Comment: Thank you! I used the 1st request , i got information of Inbox label.But i want to fetch all mails of inbox labels(such as inbox mails metadata or inbox mails thread id's) .